# How can I determine country information from whois output when two are returned?

Tags: whois

`whois 61.14.160.0` gives me the following result. Which of the two countries listed should be correct (MY or JP)?

```
% [whois.apnic.net node-2]
% Whois data copyright terms    http://www.apnic.net/db/dbcopyright.html
inetnum:        61.14.160.0 - 61.14.162.255
netname:        CORDODA-KUL-NETBLK02
descr:          Cordoda Corporation Sdn. Bhd.
descr:          Asia Netcom KUL HUB
country:        MY
admin-c:        AN155-AP
tech-c:         AN155-AP
status:         ASSIGNED NON-PORTABLE
mnt-by:         MAINT-AP-ANC
changed:        nic@asianetcom.net 20050412
changed:        hm-changed@apnic.net 20050428
source:         APNIC
person:         Asia Netcom NIC Handler
nic-hdl:        AN155-AP
e-mail:         apnic@asianetcom.net
address:        Kamiyacho Central Place 1F,
address:        4-3-13, Toranomon, Minato-ku,
address:        Tokyo 105-0001 Japan
phone:          +81-3-6430-1500
fax-no:         +81-3-6408-1501
country:        JP
remarks:        For SPAM/ABUSE Issue: abuse@asianetcom.net
remarks:        For Network Related Issue: ip-noc@asianetcom.net
changed:        apnic@asianetcom.net 20120411
mnt-by:         MAINT-AP-ANC
source:         APNIC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This are two output blocks, one for the network, which appears to be located in MY (Malaysia) and one for the company operating this network (AN155-AP, Asia Netcom), which is located in JP (Japan).